# Using dplyr to compare models

Tags: r, dplyr

I was working through the examples in the dplyr documentation of the do() function and all was well until I came across this snippet to summarize model comparisons: `` # compare %>% summarise(p.value = aov$`Pr(>F)`) `` The error was "Error: expecting a single value". So I found a way forward accessing the list of aov elements directly. This question is about sub-setting operators and to ask if there is a better way to do this. Here is my full attempt and solution.

```
    models <- group_by(mtcars,cyl) %>% do(mod_lin = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .), mod_quad = lm(mpg ~ poly(disp,2), data = .))
    compare <- models %>% do(aov = anova(.$mod_lin, .$mod_quad))
    compare %>% summarise(p.value = aov$'Pr(>F)')
    Error: expecting a single value
```

**Looking into the structure of compare**

```
    select comparison 1
    compare$aov[[1]]
    select comparison 1 and all of element 6 (the pvalues) 
    compare$aov[[1]][6]
    just the pvalues
    compare$aov[[1]][2,6]
    compare %>% summarise(pvalue = aov[2,6]) # this gets the pvalues by group
```

So I suppose I'm wondering how with an object of classes (‘rowwise_df’, ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame') that summarise can intuit the [[]] operator. And also if there might be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
 compare %>% do(.$aov['Pr(>F)']) %>% na.omit()
```

Comment: interesting....that gets the first row of the pvalues by group as well though. They are blanks

Comment: @miles2know If you want to remove the `NA`, use `na.omit()`

Comment: @miles2know `compare %>% do(.$aov)` gets all the components